# reading binary data into (py) spark DataFrame

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm ingesting a binary file into Spark -- the file structure is simple, it consists of a series of records and each record holds a number of floats. At the moment, I'm reading in the data in chunks in python and then iterating through individual records to turn them into `Row` objects that Spark can use to construct a `DataFrame`. This is very inefficient because instead of processing the data in chunks it requires me to loop through the individual elements.

Is there an obvious (preferred) way of ingesting data like this? Ideally, I would be able to read a chunk of the file (say 10240 records or so) into a buffer, specify the schema and turn this into the `DataFrame` directly. I don't see a way of doing this with the current API, but maybe I'm missing something?

Here's an example notebook that demonstrates the current procedure: https://gist.github.com/rokroskar/bc0b4713214bb9b1e5ed

Ideally, I would be able to get rid of the for loop over `buf` in `read_batches` and just convert the entire batch into an array of `Row` objects directly.

Comment: How are you currently decoding the binary data? I assume you are using the `struct` module?

Comment: I'm reading it using numpy structured arrays. I define the dtype, then read the array using the ``np.fromstring`` function.

Comment: How is data stored in a file? Can you provide a reproducible example? What is the size of a single input file?

Comment: I don't have a small example on-hand -- but the data is just a sequence of 32-bit floats

Comment: If you don't have example just simulate some data and show us how access it right now.

Comment: ok, I've made a sample notebook and added the gist to the original post above -- this generates some mock data, saves it to a file, and then reads it in to a DataFrame